# there are no more files error using express 2012 for web

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, and getting started on Visual Studio Express 2012 for web.
Worked through a couple of tutorials OK, but now I am hitting this error (more and more) when I press F5 and it tries to load IE - bombs out with "There are no more files"
I have googled extensively and tried CTRL F5, making sure that the page is in Design (not Source), Setting the page as Startup, allowing the VS2012 - and IE! - through the Firewall - using BitDefender - but no joy  o:(
I even disabled BD but same result.  I can type in the url

localhost:55137/Account/Login.aspx

and it displays fine.
Any ideas?

Just to make it more confusing, on odd occasions, even though the error is displayed, it goes on and loads the page in IE  . . .  go figure!

Regards
pitters

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had this problem today and have just found that in task manager there were a large number of ie processes hanging around.  Killing them solved the issue.

As the problem keeps reoccurring, I placed a shortcut on my desktop to kill all the ie processes.  taskkill.exe /F /IM iexplore.exe